# Creating fancy uiTableViews

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am looking to implement a "world High Scores" for a game I wrote.  I have several games already installed on my phone and was wondering how developers are creating those fancy looking "High Score" table views?

I have seen some very cool ones...some showing the scores within a view that pops up from the bottom, showing half way and then having buttons across the top of the view to show Local, and Global scores.  Orba is the game I am speaking about.

I guess what I am asking is:  Are these just regular uiTableViews with different background images and if so, does this all have to be done via code and not via builder?

Any example links would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Geo...

Comment: screenshots would be useful when referencing applications that most people probably don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

George,

I would suggest this excellent article by Matt Gallagher:  [Easy custom UITableView drawing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html).  He goes through great pains to show and explain many ways to customize UITableViews.

Without seeing a specific example, I hope this helps.